# How can I find the memory available on an SD card on a wince device (C++)

Tags: c++, storage, filesystems, pocketpc

I'm looking for a way (on a pocketPC) to interrogate the size/remaining size of an SD card.

I have to create some files on the SD card and I want to make sure there's enough room before I write to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912270.aspx

Comment: excellent.. I was just about to put in the same answer.. Thank mr jolt.. Oh it's been a long time since I've seen jolt.  Mmm